# How to change background color of dynamic navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing react native app with expo. I have created login screen but I can't to change the background color of dynamic navigation (the red area in image) in my real android phone (Android 13).
I'm using:

- "expo": "~49.0.13",
- "react": "18.2.0",
- "react-native": "0.72.5"

[image]

I try to use "react-native-safe-area-context" to cover this area. But it's not work!